# Strip tags from file contents in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that opens and reads the contents. It is a team roster that has tags formatted as "Broncos<\team>". How do you strip the tags from the team name.

```
def summarizeData(filename):
    #open the file and read the contents 
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:  
        data = f.read().splitlines()

    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 line="Broncos<\\team>"
 new_line=line.replace('<\\',' ').replace('>',' ')
```

Should give you

```
"Broncos team"
```

If you do not want the extra spaces then adjust the replace statements

Comment: Not sure them want the `team` at all; the "tag" would include the contents of the `<>`, not just the punctuation itself. Mind you, normal "tags" (in an HTML/XML sense) would use forward slashes, not backslashes, so this might be something weird.